# Resizing of Lightning page that popups from Quick Action Button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-community

I have written below code:

```
<lightning:layout >
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-medium" >            



        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                  objectApiName="Opportunity">
            <lightning:messages />

            <div style="width:300px">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.wrapperDataRec.btype}">
                    <lightning:inputField aura:id="recTypeId" fieldName="RecordType__c" 
                                          value="Manrrged"
                                          disabled="{!v.disableRec}"/>
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <lightning:inputField aura:id="recTypeId" fieldName="RecordType__c" 
                                              value="jebvjbej"
                                              disabled="{!v.disableRec}"/>
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
            </div> <br/>                   
        </lightning:recordEditForm>

        <!--</aura:if> 
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.wrapperDataRec.btype}">-->
            <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                      objectApiName="Opportunity">
                <lightning:messages />

                <div style="width:300px">
                    <lightning:inputField aura:id="brandTypeId" fieldName="my_Brand_Type__c" />                        
                </div> <br/>                    
            </lightning:recordEditForm>
        <!--</aura:if>-->             
        <h3>Related List of Contacts</h3>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters, slds-is-edited" style="margin-left:2px;">                   
            <lightning:datatable aura:id="conlistId" 
                                 data="{!v.wrapperDataRec.contactData}"
                                 columns="{!v.oppCols}"
                                 keyField="Id"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="false"
                                 showRowNumberColumn="true"
                                 onsave="{!c.handleSaveTable}"/>
            <!--selectedRows="{!v.selectedRows}"
                                 onsave="{!c.handleSaveTable}"--> 
        </div> <br/>            
        <!--
        <div style="width:300px">
            <lightning:input type="email" value="{!v.wrapperDataRec.email}" 
                             label="Email" aura:id="emailid"/>
        </div> <br/>
        -->
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters" style="margin-left:2px;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                              objectApiName="Opportunity">
                        <lightning:messages />
                        <td>
                            <label for="Country">Country</label>
                            <lightning:inputField aura:id="countyId" fieldName="my_Property_Country__c"
                                                  variant="label-hidden"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <label for=" State / Province ">State / Province</label>
                            <lightning:inputField aura:id="stateId" fieldName="State__c" 
                                                  variant="label-hidden"/>
                        </td>
                    </lightning:recordEditForm>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div><br/> 
        <br/> <br/> <br/>        
        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Send" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" />
            <div> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </div>    
            <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancelClick}"/>
        </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Popup window on Quick Action button is coming like this:

[image]

I want to this to be like this(without any vertical scroll bar, bigger size window):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things here as you didnt specify how exactly you want to resize the window:

1. Height - easy and simple configuration.

   You need to go to quick action setup in object where you're using that QA (Opportunity probably in your case) edit quick action you're using and set height as you want: 
   [image]
2. Width - slightly harder, need small hack and breaks responsivility of modal without additional styles

   ```
   <aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction" >
       <aura:html tag="style">
           .slds-modal__container {
                width : 80% !important;
                max-width : 80% !important;
            }
       </aura:html>
       <lightning:button variant="base" label="Base" title="Base action" 
           onclick="{! c.handleClick }"/>
   </aura:component>
   ```

Overriding standard modal container styles will result in wider element. But if you don't extremly need to use it just don't as you'll come against issues with RWD

Result will look like that:

[image]

on 1920 x 1080 screen